# Don't check checkbox when clicking a button inside the label

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following setup (simplified), inside the label I have some images, which activate JavaScript functions, is there a way to ignore the click on the label if the user clicks on one of these images?

```
<input type="checkbox" id="i_87" name="image[]" />
<label for="i_87" style="width:500px;height:500px;background-image:url('image.jpg');">
    <img src="bt1.jpg" onClick="somefun1()" />
    <img src="bt2.jpg" onClick="somefun2()" />
</label>
```

Just to clarify, I don't want it to check the checkbox when the images are clicked, but it SHOULD check the checkbox when anywhere else is clicked!

Comment: Remove `for` attribute from label :)

Comment: Why are you using a label if you don't want the default behaviour of a label?

Comment: **NEVER** remove the `for` attribute from a label.   :P   But, could you move the buttons outside of the label?

Comment: @Morpheus - Accessibility is the main reason.   Plus, the whole point of the label is that it ties the text to the form field programmatically . . . if you don't want the text tied to the field, use a `div` or a `span`, instead of a `label`.

Comment: See updated post sorry

Comment: @Morpheus I didn't mean to imply that it was dangerous or anything with my bolded caps . . . just having some fun.   :D

Comment: @talemyn, that makes sense, but in some occasions it's easier to remove then to re-work whole code :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must prevent the default action.  The easiest way is to `return false` from your functions.  Here is an example, bypassing your function (just return false from them and you should get the same behavior).  Tested in Chrome, but it's a pretty standard practice.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="i_87" name="image[]" />
<label for="i_87" style="width:500px;height:500px;background-image:url('image.jpg');">
    <img src="bt1.jpg" onclick="return false;" />
    <img src="bt2.jpg" onclick="return false;" />
</label>
```

Comment: Ah thanks, works perfect. Didn't make it clear in my post, but clicking anywhere but the images should check the checkbox.

Comment: just in case if you want to perform anything on clicking of image you can just pass multiple things e.g onClick="foo(); return false;"

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with CSS. In order to stop the label from checking the related checkbox, you will either have to remove the `for="i_87"` attribute, or use Javascript to stop the event from performing its default action.

In jQuery, that would be something like this:

```
$("label").on("click",function(evt) {
     evt.preventDefault();
});
```

This should theoretically then allow the click event to pass on to your images but cancel the label's default action.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `for="i_87"` from the label.

Answer (score 0):

Throwing this out there as a possibility . . . could you just move the buttons outside of the label?

```
<input type="checkbox" id="i_87" name="image[]" />
<label for="i_87" style="width:500px;height:500px;background-image:url('image.jpg');" />
<img src="bt1.jpg" onClick="somefun1()" />
<img src="bt2.jpg" onClick="somefun2()" />
```

It would probably take a little tweaking to get it to look the same, but it would make a whole lot more sense than putting the buttons into the `label` and then suppressing the default behavior of the label, but only for those buttons.

Comment: Would involve more CSS and messing around, using return false does exactly what I want so for this occasion I will do this. Although I will put them outside of the label in the future.